# How to use module variable?

Tags: python

I'm supposed to write a vending machine program, divided into three scripts (machine-user interaction, purchases and stocks).
I'm trying to create a variable `stocklist` in the stock file, so that I can call it for functions in the machine script.

machine script:

```
if stockchoice == 1:                           
    import stock
    stock.stocklist
    stock.stockchoice1(stocklist)
```

stock script:

```
stocklist = []
def stockchoice1(lista):                                           
    print("Insira o compartimento, quantidade, produto e valor:")
    stock1 = input()                                             
    lista += stock1
    print(lista)
```

I'm getting the error `name 'stocklist' is not defined`.

How can I use the variable / functions across the different scripts?

Comment: `stock.stocklist` does effectively nothing on its own. What were you expecting that to do? Also, `stockchoice` is undefined.

Comment: BTW, welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. For debugging questions, it's super helpful to provide a [mre] so that it's obvious where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stocklist` as a standalone name is in fact undefined. You need to refer to it as an attribute of its module:

```
stock.stockchoice1(stock.stocklist)
```

Or, depending on your goal, you might prefer to define it as a standalone name, like this:

```
stocklist = stock.stocklist
stock.stockchoice1(stocklist)
```

or

```
from stock import stocklist
stock.stockchoice1(stocklist)
```

Comment: I thought the "stock.stocklist" was enough to call the variable, similarly to the function. It works now though, thank you so much!